# What is the menu when you click delete contact in iPhone contact list?

Tags: iphone, sdk, menu

I want to add the menu to my app, like when you click delete in contact list of the iPhone it show up a menu with buttons "Delete" and "Cancel", is there some standard dialog for that ? I can create it myself, but i wish to know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called an [action sheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW36). The UIKit class you use is [`UIActionSheet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and your view controller should be a [`UIActionSheetDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIModalViewDelegate_Protocol/UIActionSheetDelegate/UIActionSheetDelegate.html).